# What is TVC in "TVC:UKX" symbol on tradingview?

Tags: trading, tradingview-api, stockquotes

What is meaning of TVC in "TVC:UKX", "TVC:DAX" symbol on TradingView? On other Pairs it denotes the broker providing that quotes. But in this case I don't find any broker or Exchange named after "TVC". So what is this TVC on tradingview?

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried to understand where this data is coming from, I guess an email to support would answer the question.

A guess would be TradingViewCQG (meaning data from the vendor CQG)...

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000709178 …

> On our platform, you can find instruments with the TVC: prefix. It
> doesn’t indicate any exchange, but stands for TradingView Charts and
> means that the data is calculated by TradingView. We take the data for
> calculations from different sources and after processing, display it
> on charts for free in real-time.
>
> Symbols under the TVC: prefix are usually CFDs and instruments based
> on other popular instruments, such as indices and commodities: US
> dollar index, S&P 500, gold, etc. Even though the charts of the
> original instruments and the TVC charts look similar, comparing them
> would be incorrect because they have different data sources.
>
> All available TVC symbols can be found in the symbol search: just type
> the TVC: prefix in the search field: